# Restrict jQuery spinner rounding off

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I am using a jQuery spinner.
When I set it to a value, and use step=1, I expect it not to be rounded off.
How can I do that?

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfnjzre1/

```
<input id="spinner" name="value" step=1 value="87.67">
```

The value is 87.67. With step=1, I want the value to be 88.67, not 89.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfnjzre1/10/)

Basically, jquery ui is a bit tricky when it comes to decimals - There is a globalize value called `numberFormat` that should fix this for you much simpler, but I cannot find any documentation to the right value.

Instead, I intercepted the "spin", and set the value myself - therefore allow me to change the value to whatever I want it to be.

In order for this to work both with negative and positive numbers you have to use `StepUp` and `StepDown`.

Comment: The problem is that now, every time you click, the value increments by 0.01 instead of 1. OP wants 1 at every click. And using a different type of input won't do anything, because this is generated and controlled by `.spinner`, it's a plugin applied to the input field.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry! I missunderstood the question - Ill update it.

Comment: @Paul, Yeah I want an increment of 1, and no rounding-off.

Comment: @nullpointer it has been updated. Ill update my answer in one second.

Comment: @Paul, thanks. Will look for numberFormat, otherwise will use your solution.

Comment: @nullpointer, My pleasure. I wish I could give a more straight forward answer, but this one was a ducy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/rfnjzre1/12/`
```

Let me know if this works for you. Thanks

Comment: Also, @nullpointer paul answer describe correctly. I misunderstood your question intially. Thanks

Comment: What does `$(this).siblings('input').change();` do?

Comment: @nullpointer This is the event binding with change for the spinner.